# Auto flipping div w/keyframes

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, autorotate

Hello currently I have a div where I would like it to rotate consistently without having to hover or click. here is a working jfiddle of what it is currently. I would like to make that div rotate consistently. http://jsfiddle.net/CsDLG/1/

```
h3 {
    font: 22px normal Futura, sans-serif;
    color:#333;
}
#f1_container {
    width:430px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    left:35px;
    top:10px;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-perspective:1000px;
    -moz-perspective:1000px;
    -o-perspective:1000px;
    perspective:1000px;
    margin:15px;
    }
    #f1_card {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s linear;
        -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        -moz-transition:all 1s linear;
        -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        -o-transition:all 1s linear;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transition:all 1s linear;
    }
    #f1_container:hover #f1_card, #f1_container.hover_effect #f1_card {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .face {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
        -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
        -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;
    }
    .face.back {
        display:block;
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        -o-box-sizing:border-box;
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
        box-sizing:border-box;
        color:#f5f5f5;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#f5f5f5;
        padding:10px;
    }
    .underz {
        background:url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5069/5614374365_24c4fd01d2_z.jpg) center bottom;
        width:430px;
        height:250px;
    }





<div id="f1_container">
            <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
                <div class="front face 1">
                    <div class="underz"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="back face center"><h3>We work while we play and have fun!</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a CSS3 animation to do this. (remember this feature only exists in Safari and Chrome). then, set the iteration count value to infinite.

[**here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/QuwHf/1/)

```
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```